# what does appropriately throttling the right amount of innovation mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> IT departments that aim to stifle user-led innovation
>   are often perceived as authoritarian and militaristic,
>   and at odds with their line of business counterparts.
>   Controlling risks, as the “organizational watchdog”
>   is an important role, but only if it’s coupled with the
>   unleashing of new opportunities.
>   Developing a core **competency of appropriately
>   throttling the right amount of innovation**, coupled with
>   the appropriate privacy and security constraints is a
>   skill that must be further developed and refined.
>   Decades ago, any organization that initially prohibited
>   Internet access ultimately understood it couldn’t be
>   controlled. It required new approaches to blending
>   the hiring of the right people with appropriately
>   extended autonomy, trust, and empowerment.

Comment: Throttle: to regulate the flow of fuel in an engine. Use this meaning figuratively in your sentence. That is, it could be meant to use the right amount of innovation.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom - You should add this as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OALD has throttle as:

1) the action of taking someone by the throat and restricting their air supply; choke is given as a synonym, which is interesting because it ties in neatly with the next def.

2) to control the flow of fuel or steam. (Americans call the control in a car that regulates the air-fuel mix a choke.)

So, while many Americans might remember their mother threatening to "throttle" them when they were being unruly, in this case it would actually mean *to control or regulate.*